# Node refactor if/else mess

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd love some pointers on how to refactor this

```
async function validate_request_args(req, request_type) {
    let problem_id;
    const errors = [];
    switch (request_type) {
        case "post":
            if (req.body.id == null) {
                errors.push({
                    msg: "Missing id of the problem",
                    param: "id"
                });
            } else {
                problem_id = req.body.id;
            }
            break;

        case "get":
            if (req.query.id == null) {
                errors.push({
                    msg: "Missing id of the problem",
                    param: "id"
                })
            } else {
                problem_id = req.query.id;
            }
            break;
    }
    if (errors.length === 0) {
        const problem = await models.Problem.findByPk(problem_id);
        if (problem == null) {
            errors.push({
                msg: `Problem with id ${problem_id} does not exist `,
                param: "id"
            });
        }
        return monet.Validation.success(problem)
    }
    return monet.Validation.fail(errors);
}
```

Comment: Will `request_type` always be `post` or `get`, or could it be something else like `put`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start with, I see what's likely to be a logic error. At the bottom, you do:

```
if (problem == null) {
    errors.push({
        msg: `Problem with id ${problem_id} does not exist `,
        param: "id"
    });
}
return monet.Validation.success(problem)
```

If the `problem` isn't found, you push an error object to the `errors` array, but then you return `.success` anyway and don't use the `errors` array again. In such a case, I think you want to call `monet.Validation.fail` with the error object instead, and not call `.success`.

Once that's done, note that you only ever have at most one element in the `errors` array, which `.fail` gets called with. It would be less repetitive to immediately call `.fail` and return when an error is encountered. Also, since the `fail` calls are all similar (`monet.Validation.fail([{ msg: SOME_MESSAGE, param: 'id' }])`), you can make the code DRY by putting that into a helper function:

```
const fail = msg => monet.Validation.fail([{ msg, param: 'id' }]);
```

Also, `switch` is almost never the right tool for the job IMO - it's quite verbose and can be error-prone when one forgets to `break` (which is surprisingly common). If the request type will be either `post` or `get`, use the conditional operator to figure out the property to look up on `req` instead:

```
const { id } = req[requestType === 'post' ? 'body' : 'query'];
```

I'd highly recommend against using loose equality `==`. It requires an expectation that any reader of the code understands [its strange rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35MpY.png). Better to use strict equality. Or, if the `id` or `problem`, if it exists, will be truthy (which sounds likely), it would look even nicer to use a truthy test:

```
if (!id) {
    return fail('Missing id of the problem');
}
```

If you *actually need* the logic you're implementing with `==` to check that the expressions aren't `null` *and* aren't `undefined` (but could be anything else, including other falsey values), then best to test both of those explicitly:

```
if (id === null || id === undefined) {
    return fail('Missing id of the problem');
}
```

I think it would also be useful to follow the standard Javascript naming conventions and use `camelCase` for variable names in most cases.

All together:

```
const fail = msg => monet.Validation.fail([{ msg, param: 'id' }]);
async function validateRequestArgs(req, requestType) {
    const { id } = req[requestType === 'post' ? 'body' : 'query'];
    if (!id) {
        return fail('Missing id of the problem');
    }
    const problem = await models.Problem.findByPk(id);
    if (!problem) {
        return fail(`Problem with id ${id} does not exist`);
    }
    return monet.Validation.success(problem);
}
```

Comment: your edited solution ignores cases where id=0. I've fixed it